# Backspace event on Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

This Meteor event acts as expected when running on disk top chrome but acts bad on mobile chrome.
 plese see comments in the code below, How can I get the condition `evt.which != 8` to evaluate to false when the backspace key is hit regardless of the browser?
thx

```
Template.input.events({
  'keyup input[name=email]': function (evt, template) {
    if (evt.which === 13) { // Enter key is pressed
      //do stuff
      }
    }
    else if (evt.which != 8) {
      // backspace button evaluates to false on desktop chrome
      // but evaluests to true on Android chrome.
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most desktop computers don't have a <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, they have a <kbd>delete</kbd> key. The key code for the <kbd>delete</kbd> key is `46`. Try changing your `else if` clause to the following:

```
else if (evt.which !== 8 && evt.which !== 46) {
    //should fall through to here if not backspace or delete key
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that did not do it. It still evaluates to true when the smartphone delete button is tapped. Maybe worth saying that on Mac, delete button prints 8 to the console.